# Parse server js error Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

So, I'm trying to connect to my Parse Server using Javascript.

Problem is I keep getting that parse is undefined.
I included the unpkg resource file.
I also manually downloaded that file and saved it in a parse.js file and made a reference it on my site.

Here's the code for my website

```
<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.0/build/pure-min.css" integrity="sha384-nn4HPE8lTHyVtfCBi5yW9d20FjT8BJwUXyWZT9InLYax14RDjBj46LmSztkmNP9w" crossorigin="anonymous">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<meta charset="utf-8">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login-css.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/backend.css">

 <title> iCheckIn Backend</title>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD-EJG_73OiPF-fZEu-QkEUwRoq75Ew60E"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/parse/dist/parse.js"></script>
    <script src="js/parse.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
     <div id="sideBar"> 
      <div id="standName">
        <span id="pageName">iCheck In </span>
      </div>
      <div id="avatar">

          <div id="admin">
              <img src="img/user.png" id="img"><br>
             <span id="welcomeSpan">Welcome, Admin.</span> <br><br>
          </div>
           <div id="menu">
                  <button class="pure-button menuBtn" onclick="CreateUser()">Map</button>
                  <button class="pure-button menuBtn" >List</button>
                  <button class="pure-button menuBtn " >Add Location</button>
                  <button class="pure-button menuBtn" onclick="CreateUser()" >Add Person</button>

              </div>

     </div>
</div>

<div id="fullContentDiv">
    <div id="topDiv"></div>
<div id="fullCarContent"> 
    <div id="carModels">
    <span id="span"> All Tracking Records</span>

    </div>
   <div id="showSearchDiv"> 
           <hr>
       <span id="entrySpan">Show Entries</span>
       <div id="search">
           <form class="pure-form">
           <button class="pure-button" >Search</button>
           <input class="pure-input-1-4">
       </form>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div id="map">

       </div>


    </div>



</div>

  <footer>
 Copyright © 2017 Hugo Monteiro 
</footer>

 </body>
 </html>
```

And the simple function I'm using is

```
function CreateUser(){

    var Parse = require('parse');

    Parse.initialize("mykey");
    Parse.server('myurl');

    var TestUser = parse.Object.extend("TestUser");
    var testuser = new TestUser();
    testuser.set("name","Hugo");

    testuser.save(null,{ 
        sucess: function(testuser){
            alert("Object Created!");
        },
        error: function(testuser,error){
            alert(error.message);
        }           
    });
}
```

I've already done some searching and I'm unable to come across the solution.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: One does not use `require` in browsers (without an AMD loader library)

Comment: Actually, `require` is from CommonJS

Comment: I’m following the parse documentation and it says to use require like that

Comment: Parse is defined already when you add the library to your web project. Just remove `var Parse = require('parse');`. I think it should work.